# Project columns based on list of column names in Kusto / Data Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a Kusto table that have hundreds of columns.  About half of the columns contain dates. Each date column has the word 'date' in it's name (For example: 'createdDate'). I would like to return only columns that contain "date" in the column name.

(Of note, the values in the "date" columns are strings)

I am trying to do the following:

```
let T1 = datatable (col1:string, col2:string, Date1:string, Date2:string)[
"abc", "def", "2021-11-3", "2021-11-4",
"ghi", "jkl", "2021-11-5", "2021-11-6",
"mno", "pqr", "2021-11-7", "2021-11-8",
"stu", "v", "2021-11-9", "2021-11-10",
"wx", "yz", "2021-11-11", "2021-11-12"];
let ColswithDates = T1
| getschema 
| where ColumnName contains "date";
T1 | project ColswithDates
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use "project-keep" operator

```
let T1 = datatable (col1:string, col2:string, Date1:string, Date2:string)[
"abc", "def", "2021-11-3", "2021-11-4",
"ghi", "jkl", "2021-11-5", "2021-11-6",
"mno", "pqr", "2021-11-7", "2021-11-8",
"stu", "v", "2021-11-9", "2021-11-10",
"wx", "yz", "2021-11-11", "2021-11-12"];
let ColswithDates = T1
| getschema 
| where ColumnName contains "date";
T1 | project-keep *Date*
```

| Date1 | Date2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-3 | 2021-11-4 |
| 2021-11-5 | 2021-11-6 |
| 2021-11-7 | 2021-11-8 |
| 2021-11-9 | 2021-11-10 |
| 2021-11-11 | 2021-11-12 |

Comment: Thank you Avnera, follow on question....

Is there a way to make the search case insensitive?

Comment: Currently not sorry, columns names in Kusto/ADX are case-sensitive. You can open a suggestion at http://aka.ms/kustouservoice